# can we use the same threadObj for multiple threads

Tags: python, python-multithreading, watchdog

I have written a python script utilizing the watchdog to monitor file creation in a specified folder. Once a new file is created in that folder, it's going to call a 'process' function which starts a new thread that does the real processing (and the processing typically takes a long time). My question here is that if multiple new files are created, can we use the same threadObj to spawn new threads? Here's what I do in the 'process' function:

```
def process(event):
    threadObj = Thread(target=submitRequest, args=[event])
    threadObj.start()
```

My question is that can we use the same 'threadObj' to spawn new threads for different files created in that folder? Hope this is clear. Thank you.

Comment: Note that when a `process` function ends, __its__ `threadObj` goes out of scope.

Comment: @CristiFati what does that mean? When we start a new thread and this thread takes a long time to finish, during this thread's processing, another thread is spawned with the same threadObj name. Is this fine?

Comment: The `threadObj` name is only visible in `process` func. If you try to reference it from outside (of course not assigning a value to it), you'll get a `NameError`. But yes, you can have 2 (or more) threads that will run in parallel (even in separate processes) with no problem. So (if this is what you're asking), you don't have to provide a different name for each thread you spawn.

Comment: @CristiFati What happens here is that I have written a python watchdog script to monitor new files in a given folder. Once the monitor finds a new file, it's gonna call the defined 'process' function which will create the threadObj object that will subsequently spawn a new process using subprocess.popen API. So my question is if several files are created not so far in time from each other, the monitor is gonna call the 'process' function multiple times, and thus the threadObj is going to be created multiple times for each new file created, is this fine? Hope this is clear. Thank you.

Comment: Yes it's fine."`threadObj`s" created for each thread (if multiple files are monitored at a given time) will not "fight" each other (at least not form the naming _PoV_). Also, that's easy to test.

Comment: @CristiFati Thanks!